# Dynamic Programming Tiles

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

http://www.spoj.pl/problems/GNY07H/ 
In this question we have to find number of ways to arrange 2X1 tiles in 4Xw (w >=1) rectangle ? 
I have tried this question and has given much time to it but was not able to come up with any solution . how to approach for these kinds of problem. meaning how to make dp recurrence  for them. ?

Comment: @RBarryYoung what to describe ?

Comment: tl;dr count the number of perfect matchings in an n*4 grid graph. [FKT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKT_algorithm) works on all planar graphs.

Comment: @uts the problem you are asking for help on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can build the 4xW rectangle row-by-row. When you build the next row the previous row can be in 6 different states:

```
XXXX (1 - filled)
XX-- (2)
-XX- (3)
--XX (4)
X--X (5)
---- (6 - empty)
```

For example if the previous row is (5), you have to put two vertical dominos, and then the next row is going to be (3):

```
XXXX
XABX
-AB-
```

Let `X(W,q)` denote the possible combinations of a 4xW rectangle where the last row is in state `q` and the rest is completely filled.

If you know `X(W-1,q)` for all the 6 `q` states you can easily calculate `X(W,q)`.

You know the initial states `X(1,q)` (q=1..6 -> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, invalid). So you can increase W and get these numbers for each W.

The final result is `X(W,1)` (last row filled).

Comment: In the example, do you mean previous row is 5 and next row is 3? Or am I wrong?

Comment: How do you implement it. Can you please explain with an example?

Answer (score 8):

I too am a beginner at this variation of Dynamic programming, but this link mentions http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/;jsessionid=A5053396424C9F9BBB9337ECAC9C6C17?module=Thread&threadID=770579&start=0&mc=2#1643035  that you need to apply "Dynamic programming with profiles", and that link also points to a tutorial http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=Thread&threadID=697369&start=0&mc=19 specifically, "layer count+ layer profile".

From the above link:
"This is the toughest type of DP state domain. It is usually used in **tiling or covering problems** on special graphs. The classic examples are: calculate number of ways to tile the rectangular board with dominoes (certain cells cannot be used); or put as many chess figures on the chessboard as you can so that they do not hit each other (again, some cells may be restricted)."

Other more approachable tutorials on this technique are available at:

http://sk765.blogspot.in/2012/02/dynamic-programming-with-profile.html

http://sk765.blogspot.in/2012/02/dynamic-programming-with-profile_13.html

http://sk765.blogspot.in/2012/02/dynamic-programming-with-profile_7469.html

http://sk765.blogspot.in/2012/02/dynamic-programming-with-profile_6894.html

I'm working my way through them as well.

This isn't an answer to the particular question you asked, but more of a general technique that people follow when solving this class of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a backtracking algorithm: lay all tiles horizontally first, then backtrack until you can lay a vertical tile (then forward with horizontal layering) -- eventually you will enumerate all possible solutions and each only once (a square in the last backtraking phase will either contain a horizontal or a vertical tile, which will give unique solutions, when exists).

I do not know, however if this is an optimal algorithm for solving the problem.

Comment: There are five ways to tile 2*4. There's no way you're going to be able to enumerate the >5**500 solutions for n = 1000 in time.

Answer (score 0):

Just se the pattern if by removing any 2*1 block a pattern(gemoetry ) arises such that it is againthe intermediate result, then it gives the recursive function. From that just create DP from it.

For your problem just see the link. It will explain everything

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664113/count-the-ways-to-fill-a-4-times-n-board-with-dominoes

For further refernecr juist see the link of IOI training

http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/online-study-material/topics/dp-tiling.php